# Anyone have idea how can i do this in php?

Tags: php

I am getting some IDs from database and showing on page like this

```html
2,
5,
9,
1,
7,
```

Anyone have idea how can i set and show like this in php

```html
9,
7,
5,
2,
1,
```

Comment: How are you printing these? Add code.

Comment: i am using select query  $sql = "SELECT * FROM status Where site='$site'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $id = $row['id'];
        }

Comment: It's called _sorting_. You can fetch rows from the database already sorted using an `ORDER BY` clause.
`SELECT * FROM status WHERE site='$site' ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: i am not getting table id

Comment: you can check this
here i have a table monitors where have id,site_name and site_id
and have some same value like as example.com id =3 , example.com id =1 , example.com id =8

Answer (score 0):

Use `rsort()`. Try with -

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ids[] = $row['id'];
}

$ids = rsort($ids);
```

[rsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php)